# How get an output from a function in another function?

Tags: matlab, function, handle

I have a function `Matrices` that gives me `Along`. I want `Along` from first function to pass another function `MatricesElse` as an argument. This code has error, why?

```
function theOutput = Matrices()
    theOutput = Along;


    function MatricesElse(Along)
    disp(theInput);       % // Will print value of Along returned from first function,

syms teta q u w Se Sth v p r o Y SR SA s

% // Aircraft Equations of Longitudinal Motion
Ilong=[1 0 0 0;0 1 0 0; 0 1 0 0;0 0 0 1];
Xlong=[teta;q;u;w];
Ulong=[Se;Sth];
Xlong=(inv(s*Ilong-Along))*Blong*Ulong;
teta=Xlong(1,1)
q=Xlong(2,1)
u=Xlong(2,1)
w=Xlong(3,1)

% // Aircraft Equations of Lateral Motion
Ilat=[1 0 0 0 0;0 1 0 0 0;0 0 1 0 0;0 0 0 1 0;0 0 0 0 1];
Xlat=[v;p;r;o;Y];
Ulat=[SR;SA];
Xlat=(inv(s*I-Alat))*Blat*Ulong;
v=Xlat(1,1)
p=Xlat(2,1)
r=Xlat(3,1)
o=Xlat(4,1)
Y=Xlat(5,1)

end
```

Comment: I have studied flight dynamics and 6 DoF Equation of Motion but I don't understand not only your theoretical part of your code but also what you want to do. Can you provide more detail so you would easily find someone to be able to help you..

Comment: I want to get Equation of F16 falcon and linearized it.I get A&B matrices in a function and want to get equation of "a(angle attack),q,teta,w"! can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Short explanation: you are trying to call a private variable of function `Matrices()` outside of this function, that's why it doesn't work.

This code should work. Note that the name `CalcMatrix` can differ from `theOutput` and `Along`, but all of these variables have the same content:

```
function main

CalcMatrix = Matrices()
MatricesElse(CalcMatrix)


function theOutput = Matrices()
theOutput = Along;


function MatricesElse(Along)
disp(theInput);       % // Will print value of Along returned from first function,

syms teta q u w Se Sth v p r o Y SR SA s

% // Aircraft Equations of Longitudinal Motion
Ilong=[1 0 0 0;0 1 0 0; 0 1 0 0;0 0 0 1];
Xlong=[teta;q;u;w];
Ulong=[Se;Sth];
Xlong=(inv(s*Ilong-Along))*Blong*Ulong;
teta=Xlong(1,1)
q=Xlong(2,1)
u=Xlong(2,1)
w=Xlong(3,1)

% // Aircraft Equations of Lateral Motion
Ilat=[1 0 0 0 0;0 1 0 0 0;0 0 1 0 0;0 0 0 1 0;0 0 0 0 1];
Xlat=[v;p;r;o;Y];
Ulat=[SR;SA];
Xlat=(inv(s*I-Alat))*Blat*Ulong;
v=Xlat(1,1)
p=Xlat(2,1)
r=Xlat(3,1)
o=Xlat(4,1)
Y=Xlat(5,1)
```

Comment: I saved my file by name of formula in my computer and tested your code but it has error:
??? Error using ==> plot
Conversion to double from sym is not possible.

Error in ==> Untitled3 at 7
plot(teta*180/pi,x) 
??? Undefined function or variable 'Along'.

Error in ==> formula>Matrices at 8
theOutput = Along;

Error in ==> formula at 3
CalcMatrix = Matrices()